# How to spawn a subshell, then exit from the main shell

Tags: bash, centos

I would like to spawn a subshell, so that a user can investigate the cause of an error, for example.

I expect the main script to hang while the subshell isn't exited, but this doesn't happen to be true, so the following script which I tried doesn't work as I was expecting.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

bash
exit
```

How could I achieve the desired result?

Edit after [freddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10931455/freddy) comment: OS seems to matter in this case, and I'm on CentOS. Also, bash is 4.2.

Comment: Works for me here. Check the current PID with `echo $$` before and after running the script and list the running processes with `ps aux` or `pstree`.

Comment: You mean that main bash hangs when entering the subshell? What OS are you on?

Comment: Yes, the initial shell spawns a new shell and if I exit the new shell I'm back in the original shell after the script continues and exits. I'm on Debian.

Comment: So it seems to depend on the OS - because that's what I would expect, but it's not what happens in CentOS.